# Burning M-Disks on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mount, burning, brasero, k3b, dvd-backup

I purchased an external disk writer from ASUS. This one: https://www.asus.com/Commercial-Data-Storage/SDRW08D2SU/

And M-Disks from Verbatim, these ones: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01E0CUU1C/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

But inserting the M-Disk into the disk writer, neither **Brasero** nor **K3b** seems to recognize the medium. It works if I insert a regular CD, and it mounts it, and I can browse the content. But a blank M-Disk is not recognized as a medium that I can do anything with. I obviously am looking to burn content to the M-disk.

Does anyone have experience burning M-Disks with Ubuntu? In which case, what works?

Comment: Are you sure the software you have tried even supports the M disk format?

Comment: @David I am not even sure where the error lies. If its the software or the ASUS burner, or if the error is somewhere else completely. I cant seem to find information anywhere about how to burn to Mdisks on Ubuntu.

Comment: You may try to contact the developers of [Brasero](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Brasero/) and K3b and ask them.